# I use pyscript for showing python script on browser, but not showing

Tags: javascript, python

I use pyscript for showing python script on browser, but not showing, I need solution for show on browser. So if any solution for this please share. I want to show python script on browser. Thanks

[browser inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXE1v.png)

print('Now you can!')

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it emphasizes to not use screenshots to share code. And that you should share complete code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not written `print('Now you can!')` in between `<py-script>` and `</py-script>`:

You have to link pyscript js library in `head` of your code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
```

In `body` you have to add python code:

```
  <py-script>print("Hello, World!")</py-script>
```

You can refer this blog: https://realpython.com/pyscript-python-in-browser/#write-your-first-hello-world-in-pyscript

Comment: I was pointing that he has not linked related javascript library. Code can be changed or updated.